# Clicking Next on webpage with Selenium/Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to use Selenium to click *Next* on https://www.theitdepot.com/products-Motherboards_C13.html

The relevant HTML code is:

```
<li class="page-item mx-1">
<a class="page-link rounded-pill border-0 bg-transparent text-yellow category_page_class" href="#" id="2">Next →</a>
</li>
```

So far, I have tried two ways of clicking Next unsuccessfully:

1. **Using .click()**

   ```
   from selenium import webdriver
   from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
   from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

   URL = "https://www.theitdepot.com/products-Motherboards_C13.html"

   options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
   options.add_argument('--headless')
   options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
   options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
   wd = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install(), options=options)
   wd.get(URL)

   next = wd.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value="//*[contains(text(), 'Next →')]") 
   next.click() 
   time.sleep(10)
   ```
2. **Using execute_script**

   ```
   next = wd.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value="//*[contains(text(), 'Next →')]") 
   wd.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", next)
   ```

In both cases, while I do not get any error, the Next button does not actually get clicked, and the rest of my code loops just execute over the same information as on Page 1.

Is there anything obvious I'm missing, or any other ways to click the Next button that would work on this webpage?

Comment: Are you sure the XPath really finds the element? Moreover, could you not simply get the element by ID, in my experience this is more save than using XPath.

Comment: Yes, Xpath is finding the element, I noticed in my previous trail and errors, which I havent added in the code. I've just tried finding by ID and i'm facing the same issue in that the button doesnt seem to want to be clicked.

Comment: Try to remove the headless mode and see what is happening. I tried the code myself with ID and XPath, and it seems to work. It clicks on the "Next" and goes to page 2.

Comment: You're right, I have misunderstood the problem - I seem to be retrieving the information from the first page despite the next page being clicked correctly, so this seems to be a problem somewhere else in my code. I will investigate and raise another question if required. Thank you for your assistance, if you can put your response into an answer, I will mark this question as answered.